# Why is Firefox destroying StartCom certificates?

Tags: ssl, mozilla

This is endangering my business.

Also Mozilla should be on the forefront of SSL Everywhere.

Now they are killing the only free SSL certificate authority:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1311832.

What can you say?

Is there anybody I can talk to?

Answer (score 3):

1. CAs have to meet certain requirements in order for browsers to trust them. StartCom failed this. See [this announcement from Mozilla from October 2016](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/),
   [this one from Google](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/10/distrusting-wosign-and-startcom.html) and [this from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204132) indicating removal of support from Firefox, Chrome and Safari respectively. You can talk to StartCom and indicate your displeasure of them not adhering to set guidelines.
2. StartCom isn't the only provider of free certificates: look at LetsEncrypt. If you are concerned about your reliance on free certificates endangering your business, invest in a paid certificate. A simple Domain validated certificate does not cost much (as low as USD $5 per year). Many hosting providers provide an option to enable HTTPS at zero or a nominal cost.

Comment: I thank you very much Sir. I was — not — informed about Google also distrusting these certificates. Also I did — not — know $5 certificates are available. So long.

Comment: But no company give you options that Start SSL give ! I am sure they did a mistake, but you can't compare their services with other providers ! I hope they will regain their reputation and get back in business soon, but i'm happy too that they can't make security issues !

Comment: StartCom "failed" these requirements via the fact that they were purchased by a shady cert company through 2 or 3 shell corporations.